# @State variable 'nil' after being assigned value from picker wheel

Tags: swiftui

I have a picker wheel which lets the user choose from a list of languages.  After choosing a language and hitting the start button, to begin a foreign phrase quiz, the @State variable that holds the user's language choice is nil when used in a method to obtain the phrases for the chosen language.  Of course, the phrases for the chosen language then don't display after tapping the start button.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    
    var languages = ["German", "French", "Italian", "Greek"]
    
    @State var selectedLanguage: String?
    
    var body: some View {
    
        NavigationView {
            Text("Chosen language is: \(selectedLanguage ?? "Unknown")")
            .navigationBarTitle("Test", displayMode: .inline).opacity(0.8)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Picker("Language", selection: $selectedLanguage) {
                        ForEach(languages, id: \.self) { language in
                            Text("\(language)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is going to need a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You are importing a library, and have a lot more code than is necessary to show your issue. You should not expect people to wade through all of that code to help with an issue.

Comment: @Yrb I've minimised the program and verified it still produces the problem.

Comment: Except you are pulling from a `CoreData` store that we don't have. We have to be able to run it to see the issues ourselves.

Comment: @Yrb I've used a string literal array instead of CoreData, and it reproduces the same problem.

Comment: Yes, but you need to provide us with the code so we can run it. You have still left us with the `CoreData` code.

Comment: @Yrb Sorry about that, slipped my mind. Have provided it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two alternate fixes. First, don't use an `optional` for the `selection`:

```
struct TestView: View {
    var languages = ["German", "French", "Italian", "Greek"]
    
    @State var selectedLanguage: String = "Unknown"
    
    var body: some View {
    
        NavigationView {
            Text("Chosen language is: \(selectedLanguage)")
            .navigationBarTitle("Test", displayMode: .inline).opacity(0.8)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Picker("Language", selection: $selectedLanguage) {
                        ForEach(languages, id: \.self) { language in
                            Text("\(language)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Second, if you do use an optional, you need to include a `.tag()` on your view that casts your local variable to the type of the `selection` like this:

```
struct TestView: View {
    var languages = ["German", "French", "Italian", "Greek"]
    
    @State var selectedLanguage: String?
    
    var body: some View {
    
        NavigationView {
            Text("Chosen language is: \(selectedLanguage ?? "Unknown")")
            .navigationBarTitle("Test", displayMode: .inline).opacity(0.8)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Picker("Language", selection: $selectedLanguage) {
                        ForEach(languages, id: \.self) { language in
                            Text("\(language)")
                                .tag(language as String?) //Add tag here
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Personally, I prefer the first because until you have picked a `selectedLanguage` it is `nil` and will therefore cause your view to display "Unknown" even though it look like the picker has a chose language. You will have to work around that in your UI.

Comment: I used the second, it's fine now. I've marked your reply as correct answer.